# Parsing information between two with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parsing

I'm a newbie in JavaScript and now I'm trying to parsing all information between two words. For example I have:

```
ip nat translation max-sessions 20000
interface GigabitEthernet 0/0
ip nat static-napt tcp 192.168.1.254 444 self 444
ip nat static-napt tcp 192.168.1.254 448 self 448
ip nat static-napt udp 192.168.1.254 43161 self 43161
exit
```

Actually I want to receive all information (including the end of the line) between "interface" and "exit".

Comment: Yes, we can help you. We can see your code and tell you what is going wrong with it. What we cannot do is to write code on your behalf or to guess what your code actually is :)

Answer (score 1):

Using regexp:

```
var text = "ip nat translation max-sessions 20000\n\
interface GigabitEthernet 0/0\n\
ip nat static-napt tcp 192.168.1.254 444 self 444\n\
ip nat static-napt tcp 192.168.1.254 448 self 448\n\
ip nat static-napt udp 192.168.1.254 43161 self 43161\n\
exit"

text.match(/interface[\s\S]*exit/)
```

The [\s\S] does the trick here, it matches spaces and non-spaces, hence all characters.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
var String=str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("interface"),str.lastIndexOf("exit")-1);
```

Comment: thank you it works but however in my case , it seems not really better: 1. It doesn't display "exit" 2. If i have a few blocks "interface ...exit" in my text, it displays only the last one  Do u have any solution ???<br/>

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = 'ip nat translation max-sessions 20000'+
'interface GigabitEthernet 0/0'+
'ip nat static-napt tcp 192.168.1.254 444 self 444'+
'ip nat static-napt tcp 192.168.1.254 448 self 448'+
'ip nat static-napt udp 192.168.1.254 43161 self 43161'+
'exit';

var info =string.substring(string.lastIndexOf("interface"),string.lastIndexOf("exit"));
console.log(info);
```

Comment: thank you it works but however in my case , it seems not really better<br/>
1. It doesn't display "exit"<br/>
2. If i have a few blocks "interface ...exit" in my text, it displays only the last one <br/>
Do u have any solution ???<br/>